# Bootstrap aligning

Tags: html, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap for the first time and I can't get why this is not working. I'm using ASP.Net with bootstrap. I'm trying to align the image(logo), DropDownList, TextBox and the Button in one line. 
[This is how it look now](http://postimg.org/image/60tpjesxr/) and I would like to be like [this](http://postimg.org/image/6habs3rb3/). This is what I wrote in my code:

```
 <div class="container">
      <div class ="row" style="display:inline">
           <div class=".col-xs-3 .col-md-2">
                        <a href="PiatraMain.aspx">
                            <img src="img/trapez/logo.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="Responsive image" /></a>
           </div>

           <div  class=".col-xs-2 .col-md-2" runat="server">
                            <asp:DropDownList ID="SearchDropDown" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="SearchDropDown_SelectedIndexChanged">
                            </asp:DropDownList>
           </div>

           <div class=".col-xs-2 .col-md-2">
                            <asp:TextBox ID="SearchTextBox" runat="server" CssClass="form-posytip"></asp:TextBox>
           </div>

           <div class=" .col-xs-2 .col-md-2">
                            <asp:Button ID="SearchButton" runat="server" Text="Search" OnClick="SearchButton_Click" />
           </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take out the periods before your class names

`class="col-xs-3"` instead of `class=".col-xs-3"`

Comment: Thank you, it worked. I should have know how to call a class. For alignment: I can use margin and padding and it would not effect the way it looks on phone or tablet? Let say I would like a padding of 5% for the second div,  <div class ="row" style="padding:5%">

Comment: @Dumi - I recommend reading http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid to see how the grid system works in bootstrap. In general, never touch row/column horizontal margin/padding and make sure columns are the only child elements of rows.